# How to duplicate category title and move description below product grid

Tags: magento2, layout, category

I'm just diving into template/block/layout customization in Magento 2.2 and I'd like to move my category title from being left aligned to being aligned above the description.

Currently it's like this:

```
_________________________________
|                               |
| Page Title                    |
| Description                   |
|_______________________________|
|          |                    |
|(sidebar) | (main content)     |
|          |                    |
|          |                    |
|__________|____________________|
```

I'd like for it to be like this:

```
_________________________________
|                               |
| Page Title                    |
|_______________________________|
|          |                    |
|(sidebar) | (main content)     |
|          |                    |
|          |                    |
|__________|____________________|
|                               | 
| Page Title                    |
| Description                   |
|_______________________________|
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an empty container in `main.content`.You can move description and add additional title in it.

Create:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="main.content">
            <container name="after_main" label="After Main Content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="after-main" after="-">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title" name="title.additional" template="Magento_Theme::html/title.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">page-title-heading</argument>
                        <argument name="add_base_attribute_aria" xsi:type="string">page-title-heading toolbar-amount</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>

        <move element="category.description" destination="after_main" after="title.additional" />

    </body>
</page>
```

**Description:** Above code will create a new container `after_main` with class `after_main`. We have added new page title.
Also we have move existing category description to this new container.

Comment: This is exact what I am after, is there anywhere that references the different layout xml files etc..

Comment: I am not getting your point. could please explain with example ?

Comment: Like a standard library of all the different templates/files that can be used to make overrides. Also do you know if its possible to change the above code so that the bottom title uses h2 instead of h1?

Comment: You can change `title.phtml` to `new.title.phtml` in above code.

copy `mage2Root/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml` to `app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/new.title.phtml` 

Now you can change from h1 to h2